# how to take your block button in the center of list group in react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styles, react-bootstrap

[]i want my button should be like that.but my button always stay in left[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klfVq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do it is to just use a div! or you can create a custom component that does that for you.

```
<ListGroup.Item>
  <div style={{ width: '100%', display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
    <Button variant="primary">Primary</Button>
  </div>
</ListGroup.Item>
```